# Python3 reading body text from gmail

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python3 to parse through an email and output the contents of the body in a list of strings. The contents of the body always follows this pattern:
string \n string \n string \n etc.

The error I get currently is `initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`

```
import imaplib
import email
import time
import smtplib

from_email = "someemail@gmail.com"
from_pwd = "somepass"
smtp_server = "imap.gmail.com"
smtp_port= 993

def readmail(from_email,from_pwd,smtp_server,smtp_port ):
        try:
                mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(smtp_server)
                mail.login(from_email,from_pwd)
                mail.select('inbox')
                result, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
                mail_ids = data[0]
                id_list = mail_ids.split()
                first_email_id =id_list[0]
                latest_email_id = id_list[-1] #most recent email
                result,data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
                raw_email = data[0][1]

                #read the email 
                email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
                return email_message_instance.get_payload()
        except Exception as e:
                print(e)


print(readmail(from_email,from_pwd,smtp_server,smtp_port))
```

I know the error lies after the "#read the email" comments because I was able to print out the raw_email

Comment: I'd strongly suggest getting rid of the `try` and `except` at least while you're debugging the code. Without those, you'd get a full traceback of the exception, which would tell you exactly which line its coming from, and perhaps where within the function or method you're calling the error turns up. From the message text I'd guess that some part of the code expects a Unicode string, but you're passing in an encoded bytestring.

Comment: str_email = str(raw_email)

Comment: you have not defined email_message_instance

Comment: could you help me out xero smith?

Answer (score 1):

*email.message_from_string()* expects string argument. You can use *email.message_from_bytes()* instead to fix this issue.

Alternatively, you can convert *raw_email* to a string as follows

```
mail_content = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
```

and pass *mail_content* in *email.message_from_string()*